# Unstructured Exception Handling in VB.NET 2005/2008

Tags: vb.net

I have a few VB.NET programs to maintain, that have been ported from VB6 and use the old style Unstructured Exception Handling:

```
On Error GoTo yyy
```

My question is, can I still get a stack trace while using Unstructured Exception Handling, or do I have to convert them all to Structured Exception Handling (Try/Catch) in order to catch an exception with its full stack trace.

Comment: Enrico, you should select MarkJ as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Binary Worrier, you are a gentleman sir.

Comment: Thank you both, both answers were very useful! Now I feel less guilty to avoid refactoring my old Unstructured Exception Handling :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to get the stack trace **to the line that caused the exception**, unlike the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979899/unstructured-exception-handling-in-vb-net-2005-2008/979934#979934) which just traces to the routine where your error handler is. The error might have occurred in a different routine.

In the unstructured error handlers, just use the [`GetException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.errobject.getexception.aspx) property of the [`Err`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.errobject.aspx) object to access the underlying exception - then use the [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx) property. Like this:

```
Public Class Form1

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.' 
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.' 
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle

    Call test()        
    Exit Sub 

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox("Stack trace " & Err.GetException.StackTrace)
    Exit Sub

End Sub 


Private Sub test()
    Call test2()
End Sub

Private Sub test2()
    Dim d(2) As Double

    MsgBox(d(-1))
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

As you know yourself, all things being equal, one should always use structured exception handling. However, if you can't, you can get your own stack trace by using the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class.

**NB**: Calls to stack trace are expensive, and should only be used in - ahem - 'exceptional' circumstances.

e.g

```
MethodName = (New StackFrame(0)).GetMethod.Name ' Get the current method
MethodName = (New StackFrame(1)).GetMethod.Name ' Get the Previous method
MethodName = (New StackFrame(2)).GetMethod.Name ' Get the method before that
```

Comment: This just gives a stack trace to the routine where the error handler is. If you want to know the line that caused the exception, and which routine that was in, see my answer ;)